# Was AWS Secrets Manager removed from AWS CLI commands?

Tags: aws-cli

If I enter:

```
 aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id  my secret id
```

It says invalid choice.

> aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

and doesn't list `secretsmanager` as one of the choices or any variation on `secretsmanager`?

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id  my secret id
```

was used in a [video from 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3Gn_iP3FlE)

Similarly, [this command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/list-secret-version-ids.html) doesn't work

and AWS help and AWS man don't contain secrets manager?

Comment: Could you please post which version of aws-cli you are using?

Comment: i tried with a new account with the

Comment: aws-cli/1.14.35 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.8.39

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS secrets are still accessible via the CLI.

The link you provided goes to an old version of the AWS CLI.  Check out the latest version and commands here: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/secretsmanager/index.html

Comment: thanks though
the first part of the command is still aws secretsmanager and if i do 
aws --help it dosn't display secretsmanager as an avalible option?

Comment: thanks iv got it working now from a docker instance still don't know what was wrong with it but it was likely the aws cli as you surjested so thanks!